# Binding src in embed does not work in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-chrome

I'm using AngularJs to build a web page it's working fine in IE and firefox but when i tried it in chrome it stop working. I'm wondering why it is not working in chrome and if there is a possible workaround.

**HTML**

```
<div data-ng-controller="documentController">
    <embed src={{documentId}} height="600" width="100%"/>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    (function(){

   var document = angular.module('document', []);

    document.controller('documentController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function($scope, $routeParams){
        $scope.title = 'Document';
        $scope.documentId = "document/" + $routeParams.documentId;
   }]);
})();
```

**EDIT**
The error

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /%7B%7BdocumentId%7D%7D. Reason:

    Not Found
```

Comment: Could it simply be missing `""` around `src={{documentId}}`? I.e. `src="{{documentId}}"`

Comment: I have tried both " and ' without any result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document` is a global variable in browser environment ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document)) and as soon as I know it can't be overridden (maybe it could be in some old browsers). Try to choose another name for your module to prevent bad situations.

Comment: I tried this change everything referring to document to pdf instead but no result. Posted the error i got also if it helps.

Comment: use `ng-src` instead of `src` in Angular ([ng-src docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc))

Comment: It's working now but it is a lot slower in chrome compared to other browsers. Takes around ~3000ms in chrome compared to ~500ms in Firefox. Tired it on two different computers.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to add an iframe, embed and object did not work

```
<iframe ng-src="{{ruta}}" width='800' height='350' frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
    <p>You browser not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```